# Wrong path in group policy

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I'm the it-admin in a small section of my university.
For several days, some of our employees experienced connection issues with our server (win server 2008 and win7 clients). Applications are slow and freeze often and issues while saving files (connection lost to the server).

After having a look in the eventlog, the first thing I notived were several errors concerning group policy. Event ID 1058 with ErrorCode 64

> The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows attempted to read the
>   file "\xxx.local\sysvol\xxx.local\Policies{31blablaF9}\gpt.ini" from a domain controller and was not successful. Group Policy
>   settings may not be applied until this event is resolved. This issue
>   may be transient and could be caused by one or more of the following:
>
> a) Name Resolution/Network Connectivity to the current domain
>   controller.
>
> b) File Replication Service Latency (a file created on
>   another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain
>   controller).
>
> c) The Distributed File System (DFS) client has been
>   disabled.

And `"\\xxx.local\sysvol\xxx.local\Policies\{31blablaF9}\gpt.ini"` isn't accessible from any machine in the network. But `"\\yyy.xxx.local\sysvol\xxx.local\Policies\{31blablaF9}\gpt.ini"` is. (With "yyy" as the name of the windows-server)

How can I change it to the path?

regards,
Simon

Comment: Do you have an orphaned/decommissioned domain controller that is still in AD somewhere?

Comment: Also, you should check DCDIAG /V output for any errors

Comment: browsing to \\domain.local should work from a computer.  If it doesn't, then try pinging "domain.local" from a computer and see if a DC responds.  If it doesn't, then I would check DNS domain records and dcdiag.

Comment: no this is the only domain controller that is in the AD

Comment: after a restart of the server: dcdiag /v run as admin gives no errors. as a normal user some tests went wrong due missing privileges (NetLogons, Replications, Service "NTDS") full log of the admin version: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=77JrnXLm

Comment: now after a restart of the server, browsing to \\domain.local works like a charm. before it doesn't

Comment: As a side note, you should probably be thinking about setting up second domain controller.